# как поставить кавычки вы выводе js

Tags: javascript, html5

```
bt238=document.createElement('BUTTON'); 
bt238.innerText ="всем"мир"привет";
```

Comment: Поищите "экранирование в js"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

p[0].innerText = "всем \"мир\" привет";
p[1].innerText = 'всем "мир" привет';
p[2].innerText = `всем "мир" привет`;

p[3].innerHTML = "всем &#x22;мир&#x22; привет";
p[4].innerHTML = "всем &quot;мир&quot; привет";
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```